# Draw outline around button on hover

Tags: html, css, border, transition

I would like to "draw" an outline around rectangle buttons, meaning I'd like for the border to transition but not fade in. I already have a bunch of effects on these buttons.. I tried to apply an already-made exemple of draw outline CSS but it didn't do anything..

Here's my code

```js
function hoverIcons(classnm) {
  document.getElementById(classnm).css({height: '+=30%', width: '+=30%'});
}

function nothoverIcons(classnm) {
  document.getElementById(classnm).css({height: '+=30%', width: '+=30%'});
}
```

```css
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20;
  right: 20;
  width: 80;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: Menu background;
  z-index: 10;
}

#mainicons {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 193px;
  text-align: center;
}

#mainicons i {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: -3px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  color-color: Main icon;
  background-color: Main icon background;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 30px;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .7s  ease;
  -o-transition: all .7s  ease;
  transition: all .7s  ease;
}

#mainicons i:hover {
  color-color: Hover;
  background-color: Main icon;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transition: all .7s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .7s  ease;
  -o-transition: all .7s  ease;
  transition: all .7s  ease;
}

/*-- BEGINNING BORDER EFFECT (PASTED) --*/
#mainicons {
  transition: color 0.25s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#mainicons::before, #mainicons::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#mainicons::before, #mainicons::after {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
#mainicons::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#mainicons::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#mainicons:hover {
  color: #97c5e0;
}
#mainicons:hover::before, #mainicons:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#mainicons:hover::before {
  border-top-color: #97c5e0;
  border-right-color: #97c5e0;
  transition: width 0.25s ease-out,  height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
}
#mainicons:hover::after {
  border-bottom-color: #97c5e0;
  border-left-color: #97c5e0;
  transition: border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s, width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s, height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s;
}



/*-- BEGINNING BORDER EFFECT (PASTED) --*/
/* originally written in SCSS


#mainicons {
    transition: color 0.25s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    &::before,
  &::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;}

  &::before,
  &::after {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }

  &::before {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  &::after {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  
  &:hover {
    color: #97c5e0;
  }

  &:hover::before,
  &:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  &:hover::before {
    border-top-color: #97c5e0; 
    border-right-color: #97c5e0;
    transition:
      width 0.25s ease-out, 
      height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s; 
  }

  &:hover::after {
    border-bottom-color: #97c5e0;
    border-left-color: #97c5e0;
    transition:
      border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s,
      width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s,
      height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s; 
  }
}

*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>

<div id="menu">

<div id="mainicons" onmouseover="hoverIcons('mainicons')" onmouseout="nothoverIcons('mainicons')">
<a href="/" title="Home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
<a href="/ask" title="Ask"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
<a href="/submit" title="Request"><i class="fa fa-pencil "></i></a>
<a href="/archive" title="Archive"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></a>
</div>
</div>
```

I have to admit it's very complicated for me to understand what he/she tried to do for the outline thing (https://codepen.io/giana/pen/yYBpVY).. So if you have a better/easier way to do this, thanks a lot!!

Comment: do you mean a transition from a color to another without any other fancy effects ?

Comment: No I mean going from no border to a line going around the box "ending" in a outline basically! Sorry it's not very clear

Comment: okay, it makes more sense to me,but then  i updated your snippet with plain CSS, so we can see what is going on . the border looks like coming from none to a blue one ? i'm confused again ;) might be my english

Comment: The original code is well documented with comments. Go through them again, try to understand each part, and then write it yourself without copy pasting.

Comment: Yes, but the problem with the original code is that the box has originally got an outline, and I don't want mine to have an outline? But I'll try to do that thanks @VikrantSingh

Comment: The border would start from the top left corner for exemple and then go around the whole box until it reaches the top left corner again and it has become a whole outline around the box! @GCyrillus

Comment: @MaëlleJumel did you try the answer? How did you get on?

Comment: This is what it actually does on hover in your snippet !?

Comment: @RachelGallen Actually I didn't upvote or accept because I still haven't found a solution that worked for my case although the idea is there. I upvote and accept answers on my other questions, as I indeed realise the effort people put in the help they provide!

Comment: @MaëlleJumel upvotes award effort and time contributed to helping you find an answer. It's not a code writing service. Accepts are for working answers, but you can still upvote.

Comment: @RachelGallen Ok Rachel, I'm sorry if I was rude to anyone answering.. I'm new to stackoverflow and don't really know how to use it but I'll think about it next time, sorry again

Comment: @MaëlleJumel it's okay, we're a community here, quite a friendly bunch really.. Welcome to SO.. hours of fun!! ;)

Comment: @MaëlleJumel you can upvote by just clicking the arrows around the question (but its 125 rep before you can downvote, 15 for upvote)

Comment: Yay I'm bery excited to be here, although I'm not sure I know enough about code to answer any questions yet.. Still learning and it's great to do it here! Thanks for the tips! @RachelGallen

Comment: @MaëlleJumel great! and thanks for the vote (just saw it now, yay) :)

Answer (score 1):

your html seems funny - you have html for a center button and yet none appears??

you can use just 'purple' or 'blue' etc.. for colors if you don't want to use html codes/id you find it easier, you don't need to define these in your css - that dollar sign is usually used in jquery - i haven't seen it used in css before but that's just me, i won't say it can't be used [or i'd stand to be corrected]. EDIT: [CSS vars](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) are still experimental technology with [no support in Chrome or IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables#Browser_compatibility) (although supported in edge).. as there's no support in Chrome, I'd hold off using it for now

I adjusted your code somewhat. I added a display:block to the button code so now they display one under the other in the window. Remove this and they will display as the layout will display in your original code. For purposes of snippet/[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/zyLbj9db/) window it's just handier. I replaced the colours with the html colors that you had in your definitions but like i say, in future you can just say `border-color:red` etc.

Note that this is only meant as a guide. Adjust as you see fit!

```css
button {
  display: block;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #f45e61;
  color: #f45e61;
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  &::before,
  &::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    content: '';
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}


.draw {
  transition: color 0.25s;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  height: 100%;
}

.draw::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.draw:hover {
  color: #60daaa;
  border-color: #fbca67;
  width: 100%;
}

.meet {
  border-top-color: #fbca67;
  border-right-color: #fbca67;
}
.meet::after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.meet:hover {
  color: #fbca67;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom-color: #fbca67!important;
  border-left-color: #fbca67!important;
}



.center {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
   border-top-width: 2px!important;
  border-bottom-width: 2px!important;
  border-color: #6477b9;
  color: #6477b9;
}

.center:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
  border-left-width: 2px!important;
  border-right-width: 2px!important;
  z-index: 90!important;
}

.center:focus {
  border: 3px dashed red;
  color: forestgreen;
}

.spin {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  padding: 0;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.thick {
  color: #f45e61;
  z-index: -1;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-color: #f45e61;
}

.thick:hover {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #f45e61;
}

.thick::after {
  mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
}


/* Page styling */

html {
  background: #4b507a;
}

body {
  background: #fefefe;
  color: #4b507a;
  font: 300 24px/1.5 Lato, sans-serif;
  margin: 1em auto;
  max-width: 36em;
  padding: 1em 1em 2em;
  text-align: center;
}

.buttons {
  isolation: isolate;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<!---<h1>CSS Border Transitions</1>-->

<section class="buttons">
  <button class="draw">Draw</button>

  <button class="draw meet">Draw Meet</button>

  <button class="center">Center</button>

  <button class="spin">Spin</button>

  <button class="spin circle">Spin Circle</button>

  <button class="spin thick">Spin Thick</button>
</section>
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/zyLbj9db/)

Comment: updated fiddle with added [different coloured] 'drawn' outlines.. https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/590drgfh/

Answer (score 1):

oups, i finally understood, effect is actually set on the container and you wish to set it on the links.

You basicly need to update the selector .

example

```js
function hoverIcons(classnm) {
 // document.getElementById(classnm).css({height: '+=30%', width: '+=30%'});
}

function nothoverIcons(classnm) {
//  document.getElementById(classnm).css({height: '+=30%', width: '+=30%'});
}
```

```css
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20;
  right: 20;
  width: 80;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: Menu background;
  z-index: 10;
}

#mainicons {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 193px;
  text-align: center;
}

#mainicons a {
  transition: color 0.25s;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 25px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a::before,
a::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

a::before,
a::after {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

a::before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

a::after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

a:hover {
  color: #97c5e0;
}

a:hover::before,
a:hover::after {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

a:hover::before {
  border-top-color: #97c5e0;
  border-right-color: #97c5e0;
  transition: width 0.25s ease-out, height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s;
}

a:hover::after {
  border-bottom-color: #97c5e0;
  border-left-color: #97c5e0;
  transition: border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s, width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s, height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div id="menu">

  <div id="mainicons" onmouseover="hoverIcons('mainicons')" onmouseout="nothoverIcons('mainicons')">
    <a href="/" title="Home"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
    <a href="/ask" title="Ask"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
    <a href="/submit" title="Request"><i class="fa fa-pencil "></i></a>
    <a href="/archive" title="Archive"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
 #mainicons a{ /* select here the links */
  transition: color 0.25s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative ;
  margin:0 25px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  box-sizing:content-box;

  &::before,
  &::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }

  &::before,
  &::after {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    }

  &::before {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  &::after {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
  }

  &:hover {
    color: #97c5e0;
  }

  &:hover::before,
  &:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

  &:hover::before {
    border-top-color: #97c5e0; 
    border-right-color: #97c5e0;
    transition:
      width 0.25s ease-out, 
      height 0.25s ease-out 0.25s; 
  }

  &:hover::after {
    border-bottom-color: #97c5e0;
    border-left-color: #97c5e0;
    transition:
      border-color 0s ease-out 0.5s,
      width 0.25s ease-out 0.5s,
      height 0.25s ease-out 0.75s; 
  }
}
```